# Loopback: Where does one put observers?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm relatively new to the loopback game.  How can I get observers to work?

For example, I want something to observe whenever user information is changed or a user is created.

Thanks

```
//this observer will be activated whenever the user is edited or created
User.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
    var theUserObject = ctx.instance;
    if(ctx.isNewInstance){
        anotherModel.create(theUserObject.name,theUserObject.ID);
    }else{
        anotherModel.update(theUserObject.name,theUserObject.ID);
    }
    next();
});
```

Is this the correct user of ctx?  Where should this code sit?  Within the User.js?

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? What do you want to do? Give us more info and we'll try to find a solution!

Comment: @jakerella Updated the Question.

Comment: Did you try to run the code? That's going to be the best test of what you can do. In general, yes, [operation hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Operation+hooks) should be placed in the `common/models/MyModel.js` file(s). The context object changes depending on the action.

Comment: @jakerella, is this the correct format for creating a new model -- i'm essentially propagating changes throughout our system with this observer –

Comment: @jakerella would the MyModel.js have access to the ability to create other persistent models?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it the way you have it, you can get other models through: `WhateverCurrentModel.app.models.SomeOtherModel`

Comment: Although note that `create()` is asynchronous, so your call to `next()` needs to be in a callback for the `create()` method call.

Comment: @jakerella if you can transform this into full answer i'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put this in answer (see comments above):

In general what you are doing is mostly correct. You want to put [operation hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Operation+hooks) in the `common/models/my-model.js` file(s), but that context object (`ctx`) will change depending on the hook (read the linked documentation above).

In your case, to create a new model, you need to access the `app` off of the current model and then execute `create()`, but be sure to put your `next()` callback in the callback for the create call:

```
//this observer will be activated whenever the user is edited or created
User.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
    var theUserObject = ctx.instance;
    if(ctx.isNewInstance){
        User.app.models.anotherModel.create({name: theUserObject.name, id: theUserObject.ID}, function(err, newInstance) {
            next(err);
        });
    } else {
        User.app.models.anotherModel.find({ /* some criteria */ }, function(err, instance) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (instance) {
                instance.updateAttributes({name: theUserObject.name, id: theUserObject.ID}, function(err) {
                    next(err);
                });
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: will this updateAttributes() update the specific 'anotherModel' instance that would be in created via Create() if they share the same id?  Thanks a ton m8.

Comment: is it possible to then observe the create method  via anotherModel.observe('after save')... and create a sort of cascading model generation?

Comment: Yes! Although be careful, there are "operation hooks" and "remote hooks". A "remote hook" only executes when the specified method (like `create`) is called remotely... as in from an HTTP call. An "operation hook" on the other hand (like `after save`) executes regardless of the context of the action.